How can I get rid of of smooth out weird sharp edges like this?
How can I get rid of of smooth out weird sharp edges like this?

The solutions I tried:

Shade smooth with adjusting the angle but it doesn't work
Remesh modifier
Right click subdivide + subdivision modifier

How the edge looks like in Edit mode:



You are only adding subdivisions to the corners, but the faces around also need to be smooth with a subdivision modifier. Instead of subdivide and then add the modifier, try to add the modifier and THEN some manual subdivision to smooth the transition between the corner and the large faces

As Emir says, you've subdivided your topology with a right click > Subdivide, it just adds edges between the existing edges, but it doesn't round the shape (see image below), and the Shade Smooth + Smooth by Angle won't work correctly as the angle between the faces you've created is 0:

To get rid of these edges, in Edit mode select all and press X > Limited Dissolve. Now in Object mode right click > Shade Smooth and give a Normals > Smooth by Angle modifier with an Angle value around 40° to smooth your angle:

