Why does my object get bad shading as I keep subdividing it
I have a sphere Object A which I initially subdivided 10 times, then the same sphere I subdivided again, and then 3rd time same sphere subdivided again. And I then it has this shading which doesn't look smooth, although auto smooth is turned on.
I then make another separate sphere, and subdivide it with the same amount of loop cuts 3 times   but the sphere doesn't have the bad smooth shading like object A.
Why does Blender function like this, although both objects have the same amount of loop cuts, and are the same shape?


same problem as here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/321489/how-can-i-get-rid-of-of-smooth-out-weird-sharp-edges-like-this/321493#321493 don't right click > Subdivide, it won't round your object, instead use a Subdivision Surface and apply

First time I used Smooth Modifier, fixed the shading issue, thanks for that!

Another tip when using the Subdivision Surface modifier for rounding a cube: use a Cast modifier after the Subdivision Surface, leave the Shape at the default Sphere setting and set the Factor to 1.

I do not know exactly how you subdivided the cube in your example because it already looks quite spherical, not just like a round cube. But here are two of my preferred methods to get a smooth sphere from a cube. First take a simple default cube and select it, right-click in the 3D Viewport and choose Shade Smooth. Now you can choose if you want to go procedural with modifiers to be able to change settings afterwards or destructive by doing it in Edit Mode.
Procedural
Add a Subdivision Surface modifier to the cube and set a reoslution that fits your needs like Levels Viewport 4 or 6 maybe (note that there is a separate value for rendering). Now it is a round cube, but not yet a sphere. Notice also that the Dimensions are still given as 2 m in XYZ although the sphere is much smaller (1.68 m in diameter which will only show after applying the modifier):

Then add a Cast modifier which is by default set to Shape > Sphere and set the Factor to 1. Now it is no longer a rounded cube but a sphere. Notice that the Dimensions now show the (correct) values of 1.71 m on XYZ.

If you want to make sure the resulting sphere has a specific Radius, you can enter a value greater than 0 m for it, which will be used as long as the Size from Radius option is enabled. Notice that this not only makes the sphere the desired size, but it also keeps the Scale at 1/1/1, other than if you would scale it in Object Mode and would have to apply the scale manually afterwards.

Destructive
Select the cube and switch into Edit Mode. Select everything with A, then right-click and choose Subdivide.

Now one thing you can do is repeat the Subdivide action by pressing Shift+R until you are satisfied with the resolution. To compare with the above modifier's subdivision level 6 this would be a first subdivision followed by 5 times repeating it. This leaves you with a subdivided but not rounded cube:

To make it a sphere, you can press Shift+Alt+S to activate the To Sphere tool. Drag your mouse to round the cube until it does not change anymore, in the top left it should then say To Sphere: 1.0000 or you could just press 1 to set the value.

Another way to do this instead of repeating the subdivisions and then rounding the cube manually afterwards would be take the default cube, right-click and choose Subdivide and then opening the tool options at the bottom left. There you can enter a number of Cuts (to get the same amount as before they have to be  63, note that you can only slide the value up to 10, higher values you have to enter manually). Below the Cuts is a Smoothness setting which basically gets you a sphere as well if you set it to 1. But notice that this will not produce nice smooth shading and you would have to correct it manually with Shift+Alt+S like before, so I do not recommend using the Smoothness option.

In both cases, either repeating subdivisions and rounding the result or using the number of cuts and smoothness options, the resulting spheres do not have the dimensions of the original cube of 2 m × 2 m × 2 m, but instead are 2.56 m or 3.46 m in diameter. If you want to set them to a specific size like a diameter of 2 m i.e. a radius of 1 m, you have to enter the Dimensions in the XYZ values manually and then apply the scale with Ctrl+A afterwards.
